# printf isn't working with Strings

Tags: java, class, object, exception, printf

I'm trying to make this printf work, but I keep getting an exception complaining about the first '%' operator. I have used printf many times like this, and never had a problem. I am using eclipse.

### **My Question:**

Why isn't my statement working, and how can I make it work?

### **Note:**

On line 18, the second `%` is used to represent a literal `%`

### **The printf Statement:**

```
14 System.out.printf("Symbol: %s\n"
15      + "Name: %s\n"
16      + "Previous Closing Price: %1.2f\n"
17      + "Current Price: %1.2f\n"
18      + "Change: %1.2f%", 
19      stock.symbol, 
20      stock.name, 
21      stock.previousClosingPrice,
22      stock.currentPrice,
23      stock.getChangePercent());
```

### **The Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '%'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
    at No8_2.main(No8_2.java:14)
```

### **The Values:**

(*Not* necessarily actual code in the program)

```
stock.symbol = "ORCL";
stock.name = "Oracle Corporation";
stock.previousClosingPrice = 34.5;
stock.currentPrice = 34.35;
```

### **'Stock' Class:**

```
class Stock{
    //Stock Object
    String symbol;
    String name;
    double previousClosingPrice;
    double currentPrice;

    Stock(String sym, String nam){
        //Initialize Instance Vars
        this.symbol = sym;
        this.name = nam;
    }

    public double getChangePercent(){
        //Return (in %) the change in price
        return ((currentPrice - previousClosingPrice)/previousClosingPrice)*100;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: This is a homework assignment, but I have fully written the code for it. I just need to get past this error, and have permission from my instructor to post questions like this.

Comment: It isn't complaining about that (yet). Its problem is line 14. That is supposed to add a `%` after the double in the output. @Satya

Comment: @Abdelhak I added line numbers. It's complaining about line 14. The second `%` is intentional, to turn `14.5` into `14.5%`

Comment: @AndreasFester That fixed it! Thanks! If you want, you can make a quick answer out of that and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The second % is intentional, to turn 14.5 into 14.5%

You need to escape the `%` with a second `%`:

```
System.out.printf("Symbol: %s\n"
      + "Name: %s\n"
      + "Previous Closing Price: %1.2f\n"
      + "Current Price: %1.2f\n"
      + "Change: %1.2f%%", 
      //               ^
      stock.symbol, 
      stock.name, 
      stock.previousClosingPrice,
      stock.currentPrice,
      stock.getChangePercent());
```

See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html:

> In general, the format specifier has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
> ```
>
> The following table summarizes the supported conversions:
>
> ```
> ...
> '%'   percent The result is a literal '%' ('\u0025')
> ...
> ```